# Looping a single video in a YouTube playlist using iframe API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, playlist, youtube-iframe-api

How can I loop or repeat a single video when I am using a YouTube playlist?

I am trying to check if the individual video has ended using the onPlayerStateChange event, and if so, then I am attempting to restart the current video in the playlist.

This is my code currently for trying to loop the video.

```
if (event.data === 0) {
    if (loop == 2) {
        player.seekTo(0, true);
        player.playVideo();
    }
}
```

The problem itself is that the next video begins to play and this code doesn't seem to execute. I've tried this same method on single embedded videos and it works fine, it is simply within a playlist that it does not work.

It seems to me that the reason for this problem is because the playlist automatically begins to load and play the next video upon completion of the current one, and this causes my repeat to be skipped.

If there is no way to get around this conflict of events, would it be possible to simple disable the playlist's automatic video switching? I've looked through the [api reference page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and there doesn't seem to be a way to disable this behaviour.

Edit:
Sorry I should have specified, I have a 'loop' variable that represents one of three possible states.

0: there is no looping going on

1: the playlist itself will loop (this is no problem because the api has a function for this)

2: the current video will continuously loop

Comment: How do you determine whether you want the video to loop or move to the next video in the playlist? How many times do you want it to loop?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, I have a 'loop' variable that represents one of three possible states.

0: there is no looping going on
1: the playlist itself will loop (this is no problem because the api has a function for this
2: the current video will continuously loop

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or something similar that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @DavieV hi there, have you found the solution by any chance? I'm interested in knowing how this is done as well.